# Android - Orbot Built-in App

Tags: android, proxy, tor

**NOTE:** If you have no idea what TOR or Orbot is, check out this links below: 
https://www.torproject.org/


So, I was wondering if possible to add TOR support to my app. This would save the user alot of stress looking for a working proxy and besides, TOR is one of the most safest proxies out there.

Im aware that the The TOR team made an app called "[Orbot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.torproject.android)" which allows Android devices to  proxy apps using orbot. The problem is, the only way for Orbot to proxy apps is if they have ROOT and some users do not like taking techy approaches, especially when it has "THIS COULD BRICK YOUR DEVICE!" so I thought if its possible to rip out the Orbot source and add it to my app so my app gets proxied. 


This can save lots of people from downloading multiple apps and cut time on setting this up (since my app has to have proxy support to be proxied through TOR which I havent seen much of so i really have no idea on how to have something like this) but im not sure where in the source code is the actual routing to the TOR network and thought i could get a little boost in this.
**Im not trying to make my own Orbot, i will give credit**


So, does anyone know where to start? I decompiled the regular Orbot app and skimmed through the source but not much rings a bell.


Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [ORlib](https://github.com/guardianproject/Orlib), which "is an Android Library for use by any application that wishes to route its network traffic through Orbot/Tor".

Comment: I just checked out the source and this looks like an app, do I put this into my app or how do this work? I was thinking of a library i can put inside my app but is this different?

Comment: One last thing, does the user have to have Orbot installed? By the looks of it, i think its a yes but i always want to be sure

Comment: @JockStiff: Their repo unfortunately blends the library code with a sample app. And yes, AFAIK, you need Orbot installed.

Comment: So... i guess its time for me to go do some debugging to see where the library is... well thanks... this is a good start atleast

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid forcing user to install Orbot, you can include Tor in your application using [this project](https://github.com/jehy/Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library) which includes Orbot's tor binary and allows full control over it.

Comment: It supports only up to 23 api sdk dut to apache httpclient

Comment: @Vlad that's not a problem as I already described here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294479/android-deprecated-apache-module-httpclient-httpresponse-etc/37623038?noredirect=1#comment96375875_37623038)