# In Android, why are all org.apache.http.* classes deprecated in API 22 (and what should I use as replacements)?

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection

I use `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` in my app, and a bunch of other classes like HttpStatus, SSLSocketFactory, PlainSocketFactory, SchemeRegistry, etc. But as of API 22 thery're all being marked as deprecated, and I don't see any clear indication as to what replaced them. The documentation jas says to "Please use [openConnection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()) instead. Please visit [this webpage](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) for further details", and that doesn't make it very clear what to do. `openConnection()` just points to the URL class, and the webpage link is from 2011 that talks about the differences between the Apache classes and `HttpUtrlConnection`. So, does that mean that we're supposed to be useign `HttpUrlConnection` class from now on? And if that's the case, I thought that it wasn't thread safe (which is why I was using the `ThreadSafeClientConnManager`).

Could someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32202597/2590478).

Comment: You can still use apache's libraries. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37623038/1727132

Comment: Because there is the alternative HttpURLConnection class which reduces network use and power consumption. Source: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Answer (score 5):

I asked something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29098181/how-to-use-urlconnection-now-that-org-apache-http-decapitated)  about half month ago. As it turns out we have to use only openConnection() instead of the old ones.

I think it's a bit early to change your code, as Lollipop is on a few amount of smartphones, but you should change it so you can cut ahead of time. I got a pretty good idea from here how to a connection [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) and also try to search for "httpurlconnection example"

Also about thread safety [this](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=32076), hope it helps

(I tried to post it as a comment but I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Tanks for the post, but I already know how to use HttpUrlConnection. I just need to have someone confirm that it's beasically supposed to replace HttpClient, and what to do about thread safety. Your link confirmed that it's not thread-safe, but I don't see anything that shows how to use it in a threaded environment when I want to make concurrent connections.

Answer (score 2):

Use this HttpUrlConnection as an alternate

```
public String  performPostCall(String requestURL,
            HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostData(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            }
            else {
                response="";

                throw new HttpException(responseCode+"");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

....

```
  private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29561084/4552938)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post, but I already know how to use HttpUrlConnection. I wanted to know if that's what we're supposed to use now (since the API docs are very vague), and what we're supposed to do about it not being thread-safe. What are we supposed to use instead of ThreadSafeClientConnManager?

Comment: Read this: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html