# Cannot Retrieve data from php mysql to android activity

Tags: android, mysql, json, codeigniter

Im new to android programming. So here's the problem. 
I am currently using a php framework codeigniter to query my data from mysql. When i type the url in my browser i see my json data. But when i retrieving it in my android activity it returns null.
Here is my code.
php code

```
function getdrug(){
            $id = $_GET['letter'];
            //echo $_GET['letter'];
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            if($id == 'a'){
                $this->db->like('Generic_Name','A');
                $value['Drugs'] = $this->db->get('drugs')->result();
                echo json_encode($value);
            }
    }
```

my android activity

```
ListView lv;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String URL = "http://emedteam-001-site1.ctempurl.com/emed/home/getdrug?letter=a";
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),URL + "\n" +jsonobject, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   }
    });
```

my JSONfunctions

```
public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(final String URL){
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        String params = "";

        JSONObject jArray = null;


        try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        //Convert
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
         }
        //parse json data
         try {

                jArray = new JSONObject(result);
                System.out.print(jArray);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
        return jArray;

    }
}
```

here's the link of my url http://emedteam-001-site1.ctempurl.com/emed/home/getdrug?letter=a

Answer (score 0):

HTTPClient is deprecated so you should avoid it. Look at this [HttpClient is deprecated (android studio, Target=api 22)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220902/httpclient-is-deprecated-android-studio-target-api-22)

This is my working function to get content from json

```
    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(final String URL){

        JSONObject jArray = null;
        try {
            //URL = "http://emedteam-001-site1.ctempurl.com/emed/home/getdrug?letter=a";
            URLConnection conn = new URL(URL).openConnection();
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            String str = sb.toString();
            sb = null;
            jArray  = new JSONObject(str);                          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jArray;  
    }
```

**EDITED:** You need to call to this function inside AsyncTask to avoid [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

```
ListView lv;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new StackOverflowTask().execute();
        }
    });

    class StackOverflowTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                JSONObject test = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://emedteam-001-site1.ctempurl.com/emed/home/getdrug?letter=a");
                return test;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject test) {
            if(test != null)
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Hello Stackoverflow ;)",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I hope it help!

Comment: Thanks Sir. im getting a error when im return the o variable

Comment: I edit my answer to fit your getJSONfromURL function

Comment: Sir can i know is the use of variable o ? Im getting a error with that

Comment: i just removed o from the code and replaced by jArray, try again

Comment: Nothing Happened Sir :(. By the way sir. Im using ECLIPSE :( not android studio

Comment: you've  set <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I test the code, the problem is that you are not calling the function inside an AsyncTask check this answer to get a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/4848308 and error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException is raised, the problem is that you are performing a networking operation on a main thread.

Comment: Thanks a for your effort sir. I appreciate it. I'll wait

Comment: I add StackOverflowTask to my answer and a sample code of how to use inside of your onCreate

Comment: sir the object is not null. it  outputs the onPostExecute. Is that right ?

Comment: Yeap, onPostExecute you should get your Jsonobject as I did in my sample project  :) If you encounter my help valuable please mark the question as answered ;)