# Apache HTTP Client Removal from API23, will that have an effect on Volley?

Tags: android, apache, httpresponse, android-volley, android-api-levels

As we have known that `Apache HTTP Client` removed in **API 23**

[Apache HTTP Client Removal](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

However, `Volley` library currently still uses `Apache`'s library such as

```
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils;
```

And I have tested 2 projects: one with `compileSdkVersion 22`, the other with `compileSdkVersion 23`, got 2 screenshots:

**compileSdkVersion 22**

[image]

**compileSdkVersion 23**

[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. Of course, API23 projects using Volley still work successfully.
   However, I don't understand how they use the `Apache`'s library at runtime, do they
   find in API22 or lower instead?
2. Moreover, I wonder if in the near future, will Volley be upgraded so
   that no longer uses `Apache`'s library? If not, will my current projects still work in the future when `Apache`'s library completely removed and not supported?

Perhaps my English is not so clear, however, hope that you understand my question.

Any explanation will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

From @random's comments, I created a new API23 project using Google's official Volley library (I mean by `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley` as Google suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)), instead of using `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'` in `build.gradle` file. Yes, got errors with lack of Apache library when building project. Must add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` into `build.gradle` file as documented.

---

**2nd UPDATE:**

I have just customized Google's volley (as a module in my project) removing Apache library. Please go to [my GitHub sample project](https://github.com/ngocchung/VolleyNoApache) for your reference. However, please note that it has not been fully tested for all cases, and I have tested only 02 simple cases: `GET` and `POST` requests with my web service that is `ASP.NET Web API`.

Comment: The more pressing issue IMO is that Volley, which is a Google library, is implemented using deprecated code, which as of v23 is actually excluded from the sources. Using the `useLibrary 'org.apach.http.legacy'` flag is a workaround to keep legacy code when it was intentionally removed. I'd expect Volley to either overhaul the entire code to remove the apache components, or declare that this library will not be developed much further. Things are pretty vague at the moment.

Comment: @ItaiHanski: I have just customize Google's volley (as a module in my project) removing Apache library. Please go to my GitHub link https://github.com/ngocchung/VolleyNoApache. Please note that it has not been fully tested for all cases :)

Comment: another highly extended option for volley replacement is https://github.com/apptik/jus

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems there has been quite a mess with the Volley library in Android M. A bug has already been filed for it and acknowledged by google.

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3013

You should star and track it for any further updates

UPDATE

Regarding your first question, you don't get an error for missing `apache` files because the library that you're using is still compiled using API 22

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=22
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=22.0.1
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=22
```

https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/gradle.properties

Also check this [open issue](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/issues/92) from the library
according to which you can add legacy library

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide more information relating to my 1st question?

Comment: The issue reported says the code will not compile due to missing apache files. Not sure if you've included external apache library and what are your build settings.

Comment: I don't include apache in `libs` folder. build.gradle `android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23        
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}`

Comment: `android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.simplevolley"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
}`

Comment: does that mean if I remove API22 from Android SDK, API21 or lower will be used instead (at the present, I have no environment to test)

Comment: It might complain you to add API 22 first. It would be good if you add `volley` in the way google suggests to add, library that you're using is not provided by google. It just updates itself from google sources occasionally and has its own build settings. If you add volley in the recommended way you'll have to add external legacy apache library but that ways you'll know how everything is linked together

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify `the way google suggests` more? You mean getting the source code from `GitHub` then compile to `JAR` file, put it into `libs` folder instead of using `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'` in build.gradle file?

Comment: You know, when starting using Volley, I firstly want to use the google source, then I find something missing, as [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737844/android-volley-why-in-jsonarrayrequest-java-has-no-constructor-jsonarrayrequest), please take a look :)

Comment: :) volley isn't stable right now, so you'll get such issues. Regarding the `recommended` way, you either include the jar as you mentioned or include it as a module. With the module way, you can go and look into the source code, fix bugs yourself, like adding the missing constructor as mentioned in your other question. You can do that with the jar also but will have to recreate it everytime. If you decide to use volley, you'll have to struggle a bit till it gets more stable.

Comment: Your comments are really helpful, thank you very much once again, nice day :)

Comment: I have just updated my question after testing a new project using Google's official Volley library :)

Answer (score 8):

Apache HTTP Client Removal
This preview removes support for the Apache HTTP client. If your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3 (API level 9) or higher, use the HttpURLConnection class instead. This API is more efficient because it reduces network use through transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power consumption. To continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Android is moving away from OpenSSL to the BoringSSL library. If you’re using the Android NDK in your app, don't link against cryptographic libraries that are not a part of the NDK API, such as libcrypto.so and libssl.so. These libraries are not public APIs, and may change or break without notice across releases and devices. In addition, you may expose yourself to security vulnerabilities. Instead, modify your native code to call the Java cryptography APIs via JNI or to statically link against a cryptography library of your choice.

Comment: Thanks! However, my projects don't use Apache's library directly, just use Volley, so no need to declare that line in build.gradle

Comment: Hi! Your answer will works fine for API23 projects using official volley from Google (I mean by `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley`). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the de dependencies of your app, and then works correctly:

dependencies {
...
  compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}

Comment: Hi! As I mentioned in my question, API23 projects using Volley still work successfully

Answer (score 0):

It's one huge hysteria about Apache's HTTP client. You can continue using it in any project you want without any consequences. Why waste time porting code to other libraries? I described the best way to continue using Apache's libraries here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37623038/1727132 (spoiler: don't use legacy version!)

Answer (score 0):

`Appache Http` is removed from android `API level 23` if you still using the Apache Http client you can include `android {  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'}` in your `project - module build.gradle`