# What's the best way to upload an image or file using Volley library now that apache's MultipartEntityBuilder is deprecated?

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley, multipart

I used to have a combination of a child of the `Request` object that uses a `MultipartEnityBuilder` and `HttpEntity` to upload images and files. Now that it is deprecated, and now that I have migrated to Android Studio, I am looking for a more updated way to do the above task but using the currently best way to do it that is compatible from API 15 onwards.

I tried searching but Google still returns the guides and questions here on SO that references `MultipartEntityBuilder` and `HttpEntity`, so I figured I could ask

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity yet?

Comment: Yes, but the `byte[]` variable passed into the constructor, how do you get that? And what if there are multiple files to be uploaded?

Comment: In my sample code, byte array got from `getFileDataFromDrawable`, and I have uploaded 2 files `// the first file
            buildPart(dos, fileData1, "ic_action_android.png");
            // the second file
            buildPart(dos, fileData2, "ic_action_book.png");`

Comment: I really like this solution, let me make a more compact and modular class using your solution. I'll post it a bit later

Comment: Actually, my solution is not perfect, because Google's volley has used Apache's library inside it, as you can easily find `HttpResponse` or `HttpEntity` in BasicNetwork class and others. I also had a question at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472263/apache-http-client-removal-from-api23-will-that-have-an-effect-on-volley. Pls take a look.

Answer (score -1):

You are right, `MultipartEntity` is deprecated, but you can now use `MultipartEntityBuilder`. Here is an example:

```
private void uploadVideo(String videoPath) {
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        File file = new File(videoPath);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(server +"/api/docfile/");

        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("uploadfile", file);
        // add more key/value pairs here as needed

        HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
        post.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();

        Log.v("result", EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same way I am doing it right now. What library or package are you using to be able to use MultipartEntituBuilder and HttpEntity?

Comment: download  Apache HttpClient Mime 4.3.1 jar file from  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.1 and add it to your eclipse or android studio project

Comment: Isn't apache deprecated?

Answer (score -1):

You could have made it clear in your post, if thats the case yes it is,it was deprecated in API 22, you can now use URLconnection, here is a sample":

```
private StringBuffer request(String urlString) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

StringBuffer chaine = new StringBuffer("");
try{
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();

    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        chaine.append(line);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    // writing exception to log
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return chaine;
```

}