# Volley Source using deprecated methods

Tags: android, android-volley

I tried to use volley for my network communication instead of conventional HTTP request and in order to avoid Async Task. But when I imported volly source, I found that inside it uses some deprecated classes, eg. a class named HurlStack uses various deprecated classes such as HttpResponse, StatusLinem. Is there any way to use an up to date volley?

Comment: Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472263/apache-http-client-removal-from-api23-will-that-have-an-effect-on-volley

Comment: Thank you. So it seem I have to find another option.

Comment: If you still want volley, update build.gradle file as mentioned in my link :)