# Upload file via POST request without HttpClicent

Tags: android, rest, httpclient, deprecated

As I read, `HttpClient` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294479/android-deprecated-apache-module-httpclient-httpresponse-etc) since *Android API 22*. That's why I don't want to use it. I need to upload file vie `POST` request with possibility to track upload progress. Is there way to do it?

Comment: If prefer Volley, you can take a look at [my topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity) or search HttpUrlConnection, OkHttp or Retrofit multipart POST request, many topics available in StackOverflow

Comment: iirc, Android has OkHttp bundled since a few versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HttpUrlConnection with Asyctask to show progress.

Also you can refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/) for the same.