# No more support for Apache HttpClient in marshmallow

Tags: android, json, rest

I am new to android studio, I have came to know that android is not supporting Apache HttpClient more. So What should I have to choose alternative for implementation of Android web services with JSON. Which API will be fit to target greater than 16 API level.

Comment: use HttpURLConnection instead. :)

Comment: most popular are volley ,retrofit though lot other are available  depend upon

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294479/android-deprecated-apache-module-httpclient-httpresponse-etc

Comment: How can I add HttpURLConnection library to my project. Will this only be enough for me to make Http (GET or POST) Request upon server for getting JSON Data? @HuyN

Comment: @Usman This article is all you need :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily

Comment: Thanks! This topics really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **HttpURLConnection** instead.

Or some libraries like:

**Retrofit**: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

**Volley**: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

**OkHttp**: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Read this article about comparision: [Comparison of Android networking libraries: OkHTTP, Retrofit, and Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley)