# Do new libraries work with older android devices?

Tags: android, apache, http, urlconnection

I am trying to build an android app, exchanging data with a PHP server via JSON. Thus I need to learn working with GSON, `org.apache.http.*` libraries - so called

> apache library module

.

I've studied several examples that use lib classes like `HttpClient`, `HttpEntity`, `HttpResponse` and the like.
When I try to add similar code into my app, I get a warning that virtually all library classes with Http* prefix are deprecated.

I have learned that Android team has deprecated apache module since API 22+

There are sevaral threads suggesting to use `URLConnection` instead.
[Like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294479/android-deprecated-apache-module-httpclient-httpresponse-etc).

My question is: Will my app work on older android devices (android 2.0.x - 4.4), if I'd follow the advice to use URLConnection ? I build on AndroidStudio 2.1.2 / Gradle.

If there is even better option than URLConnection, your hint will be appreciated. No proprietary libraries, please. I prefer standard stuff.

Comment: Try [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) with its [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Comment: @tynn Thanks, nice tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will my app work on older android devices (android 2.0.x - 4.4), if I'd follow the advice to use URLConnection ?

`HttpURLConnection` is not recommended prior to Android 2.2 due to bugs. Since few devices run such Android versions, this should not be a major impediment. Otherwise, `HttpURLConnection` works fine, though its API leaves something to be desired. Personally, I recommend [OkHttp3](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Comment: Great. That suffices :)