# The App is showing warnings related to HttpClient and HttpGet()

Tags: android, esp8266

Warnings for HttpClient,HttpGet().
The code is running but  it is not getting any response from the Esp8266(I have used Esp8266 as a server in my application).

Is it related to the warnings of HttpClient or HttpGet() as shown in the image or related to the Esp8266 coding?
Please guide!

[image]

Comment: Link for the Image :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkfaW.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPClient is deprecated since API 22. You can try using HttpURLConnection instead.

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
```

More info in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29889139/5040796